# How to get Testcafe to fail on the not allowed CORS headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, cors, testcafe

I'm testing that the production web app has only allowed CORS HTTP headers. In my tests, the sent illegal CORS headers bypass the browser validations since the request goes and comes from a proxy URL located on the same origin. for example:

```
Request URL: http://192.168.0.139:43561/T87i44N5N*DrJe7nq7U/https://example.com/cart
```

My HTTP request contains the following custom HTTP header:

```
evil-header: break-it
```

In the response, this header is not allowed in the `access-control-allow-headers` value and supposed to cause a CORS error.

```
access-control-allow-headers: authorization, accept-currency, accept-language, cookie, content-type, context-campaign, context-container-name, csrf-token, customer-id, experiments, geo-ip-country, origin, referer, session-id, visitor-id
```

Despite this, the request returns with status code 200 and the test does not fail.

Comment: If the request goes and comes from a proxy URL located on the same origin, then the request isn’t a CORS request https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-request and so the browser doesn’t use the CORS protocol — which means the browser does no checking of any of the Access-Control-\* response headers. So to run the test you either need to make the request directly to the `https://example.com/cart` endpoint, or else you need to run the proxy at some origin that’s not the same as the frontend code (e.g., run it on a different port).

Comment: thanks, @sideshowbarker. I found some posts that said Testcafe should return with status code 222 if a CORS error happens. Should be the same in my case?
May you know why the request goes against this proxy URL and how can I make it direct?

Comment: This behavior looks like a bug. I reproduced it on my side. I opened an issue in the TestCafe hammerhead repository to research it: [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/2535](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/2535). Please track it to be notified about our progress.

As a workaround, you can try to use [RequestHooks](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/intercept-http-requests.html#create-a-custom-request-hook) to handle this manually.

Comment: I cannot reproduce [the issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/2535) using `testcafe@1.10.2-alpha.1`. Please check your scenario with this alpha version.